# Flexbox horiz/vert centering goes outside of <img>

Tags: css, flexbox

Trying to center `Hello world` horizontally/vertically inside `.test` while `.test` stretches to the size of `.test img`. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/x06q69cc/

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.test img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.test .test2 {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400">
  <div class="test2">
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you made `.test` a flexbox, the `<img>` and `.test2` inside it will behave similarly in a flex child element fashion, which means that the `<img>` and `.test2` will appear side by side.

One solution would be to make `.test2` a flexbox instead of `.test` and have `.test2` be absolutely positioned over `.test`.

```css
.test {
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.test img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.test .test2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
    <div class="test2">
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much phantomesse!